# Upper bound for the VC dimension of NN with $L$ layers of $d$ nodes each

Tags: neural-networks, vc-dimension

I'm trying to give an upper bound for the VC dimension of the hypotheses class $H$ of NN with binary output, $L$ layers (feedforward, fully connected), each layer except the output layer contains $d$ nodes, and sign is the activation function.

The idea is first to find the number of parameters $N$ of the network, and to show that $2^m \le (em)^N \Rightarrow m \le 2N\log_2(eN)$.

Given that, it is supposed to be easy to derive the VC dimension bound, as the growth function of this class is $2^m=\Pi_H(m) \le (\frac{em}{d+1})^{dL(d+1)}$.

As I understand it, the number of parameters is defined by the number of edges in the network. By a simple calculation I got that $N = d+(L-1)d^2$. Yet, I'm not sure how to prove the inequality.